# Remove black bubbles and crosses at links using Visual Paradigm

Tags: uml, visual-paradigm

I used UML to design my class diagram, how can i remove the black bubble at the end of the connector. Also how to remove the X on the link

[image: UML Class Diagram]

Thanks in advance

Comment: what kinda software are you using?! and as I seeing the diagram, it's okay.

Comment: @user2511414  It is VP-UML. And it is said in the header of the question.

Answer (score 0):

To remove "X" on the association link:

1. Select association link and press "Enter" or select "Open Specification ..." on association link popup menu.
2. Set 'Navigable' property to "True" on the 'Booking class' association side.

Answer (score 0):

As for the point,

- right-click the connection, Pop-up Menu
- open Specification - it is `association specification`
- click the `...` button in Role Customer.
- In the appeared form of `association end specification`, find `Owned By` field and change its content from the class to the connection itself.

As for the cross,

- in `Association Specification` change the Navigable field of the end to true. Both arrow and cross disappear.
- change the mentioned to unassigned - only cross disappears.

I can't find the way to show a connector with one end empty and another as an arrow without changing the sense of the connection.

By right click -> Popup menu -> Presentation Options -> Show Navigation arrows -> hide all arrows and crosses, you can hide so BOTH arrow and cross.